# jquery-addresspicker how to change default location

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have downloaded this [demo](http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html)

How can I change the default location (France to some other county)? I have tried it but I was unable to locate the place to change.
Here is the original source [code](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker)

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * jQuery UI addresspicker @VERSION
 *
 * Copyright 2010, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Depends:
 *   jquery.ui.core.js
 *   jquery.ui.widget.js
 *   jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
 */
(function( $, undefined ) {

  $.widget( "ui.addresspicker", {
    options: {
        appendAddressString: "",
        draggableMarker: true,
        regionBias: null,
        componentsFilter:'',
        updateCallback: null,
        reverseGeocode: false,
        autocomplete: 'default',
        mapOptions: {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 2),
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        elements: {
            map: false,
            lat: false,
            lng: false,
            street_number: false,
            route: false,
            locality: false,
            administrative_area_level_2: false,
            administrative_area_level_1: false,
            country: false,
            postal_code: false,
            type: false

        },
        autocomplete: '' // could be autocomplete: "bootstrap" to use bootstrap typeahead autocomplete instead of jQueryUI
    },

    marker: function() {
      return this.gmarker;
    },

    map: function() {
      return this.gmap;
    },

    updatePosition: function() {
      this._updatePosition(this.gmarker.getPosition());
    },

    reloadPosition: function() {
      this.gmarker.setVisible(true);
      this.gmarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat.val, this.lng.val));
      this.gmap.setCenter(this.gmarker.getPosition());
    },

    selected: function() {
      return this.selectedResult;
    },
    _mapped: {},
    _create: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.geocoder = {
        geocode: function(options, callback)
        {
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + jQuery.param(options) + '&sensor=false',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
              callback(data.results, data.status);
            }
          });
        }
        //new google.maps.Geocoder();
      };

      if (this.options.autocomplete === 'bootstrap') {
          this.element.typeahead({
            source: function(query, process) {
                self._mapped = {};
                var response = function(results) {
                    var labels = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        self._mapped[results[i].label] = results[i];
                        labels.push(results[i].label);
                    };
                    process(labels);
                }
                var request = {term: query};
                self._geocode(request, response);
            },
            updater: function(item) {
                var ui = {item: self._mapped[item]}
                self._focusAddress(null, ui);
                self._selectAddress(null, ui);
                return item;
            }
          });
      } else {
        this.element.autocomplete($.extend({
            source: $.proxy(this._geocode, this),
            focus:  $.proxy(this._focusAddress, this),
            select: $.proxy(this._selectAddress, this)
        }), this.options.autocomplete);
      }

      this.lat      = $(this.options.elements.lat);
      this.lng      = $(this.options.elements.lng);
      this.street_number = $(this.options.elements.street_number);
      this.route = $(this.options.elements.route);
      this.locality = $(this.options.elements.locality);
      this.administrative_area_level_2 = $(this.options.elements.administrative_area_level_2);
      this.administrative_area_level_1 = $(this.options.elements.administrative_area_level_1);
      this.country  = $(this.options.elements.country);
      this.postal_code = $(this.options.elements.postal_code);
      this.type     = $(this.options.elements.type);
      if (this.options.elements.map) {
        this.mapElement = $(this.options.elements.map);
        this._initMap();
      }
    },

    _initMap: function() {
      if (this.lat && this.lat.val()) {
        this.options.mapOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat.val(), this.lng.val());
      }

      this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement[0], this.options.mapOptions);
      this.gmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.options.mapOptions.center,
        map:this.gmap,
        draggable: this.options.draggableMarker});
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.gmarker, 'dragend', $.proxy(this._markerMoved, this));
      this.gmarker.setVisible(false);
    },

    _updatePosition: function(location) {
      if (this.lat) {
        this.lat.val(location.lat());
      }
      if (this.lng) {
        this.lng.val(location.lng());
      }
    },

    _addressParts: {street_number: null, route: null, locality: null,
                    administrative_area_level_2: null, administrative_area_level_1: null,
                    country: null, postal_code:null, type: null},

    _updateAddressParts: function(geocodeResult){

      parsedResult = this._parseGeocodeResult(geocodeResult);

      for (addressPart in this._addressParts){
        if (this[addressPart]){
          this[addressPart].val(parsedResult[addressPart]);
        }
      }
    },

    _updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode: function(location){
      this.geocoder.geocode({'latlng': location.lat() + "," + location.lng()}, $.proxy(function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){

          this._updateAddressParts(results[0]);
          this.element.val(results[0].formatted_address);
          this.selectedResult = results[0];

          if (this.options.updateCallback) {
            this.options.updateCallback(this.selectedResult, this._parseGeocodeResult(this.selectedResult));
          }
        }
      }, this));
    },

    _parseGeocodeResult: function(geocodeResult){

      var parsed = {lat: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lat,
        lng: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lng};

      for (var addressPart in this._addressParts){
        parsed[addressPart] = this._findInfo(geocodeResult, addressPart);
      }

      parsed.type = geocodeResult.types[0];

      return parsed;
    },

    _markerMoved: function() {
      this._updatePosition(this.gmarker.getPosition());

      if (this.options.reverseGeocode){
        this._updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode(this.gmarker.getPosition());
      }
    },

    // Autocomplete source method: fill its suggests with google geocoder results
    _geocode: function(request, response) {
        var address = request.term, self = this;
        this.geocoder.geocode({
          'address': address + this.options.appendAddressString,
          'region': this.options.regionBias,
          'components': this.options.componentsFilter
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  result = results[i]
                  g = result.geometry
                  g.location = new google.maps.LatLng(g.location.lat, g.location.lng);
                  g.viewport = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(g.viewport.southwest.lat, g.viewport.southwest.lng),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(g.viewport.northeast.lat, g.viewport.northeast.lng)
                  )
                  result.label =  results[i].formatted_address;
                };
            }
            response(results);
        })
    },

    _findInfo: function(result, type) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i++) {
        var component = result.address_components[i];
        if (component.types.indexOf(type) !=-1) {
          return component.long_name;
        }
      }
      return false;
    },

    _focusAddress: function(event, ui) {
      var address = ui.item;
      if (!address) {
        return;
      }
      if (this.gmarker) {
        this.gmarker.setPosition(address.geometry.location);
        this.gmarker.setVisible(true);
        this.gmap.fitBounds(address.geometry.viewport);
      }

      this._updatePosition(address.geometry.location);

      this._updateAddressParts(address);

    },

    _selectAddress: function(event, ui) {
      this.selectedResult = ui.item;
      if (this.options.updateCallback) {
        this.options.updateCallback(this.selectedResult, this._parseGeocodeResult(this.selectedResult));
      }
    }
  });

  $.extend( $.ui.addresspicker, {
    version: "@VERSION"
  });

  // make IE think it doesn't suck
  if(!Array.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
      for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
        if(this[i]==obj){
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
  }

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: You can try to change argument in this "center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 2)," code provide latitude and longitude for which country you want

Comment: Can you please create fiddle for this so I can give you correct answer

Comment: thank you @YogeshSharma I got it now

Answer (score 1):

Change:

1. the componentsFilter
2. regionBias
3. the center of the map

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q6otdp1/) (changed to US)

```
(function () {
    var addresspicker = $("#addresspicker").addresspicker({
        componentsFilter: 'country:US'
    });
    var addresspickerMap = $("#addresspicker_map").addresspicker({
        regionBias: "us",
        updateCallback: showCallback,
        mapOptions: {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024,-95.712891),
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        elements: {
            map: "#map",
            lat: "#lat",
            lng: "#lng",
            street_number: '#street_number',
            route: '#route',
            locality: '#locality',
            administrative_area_level_2: '#administrative_area_level_2',
            administrative_area_level_1: '#administrative_area_level_1',
            country: '#country',
            postal_code: '#postal_code',
            type: '#type'
        }
    });

    var gmarker = addresspickerMap.addresspicker("marker");
    gmarker.setVisible(true);
    addresspickerMap.addresspicker("updatePosition");

    $('#reverseGeocode').change(function () {
        $("#addresspicker_map").addresspicker("option", "reverseGeocode", ($(this).val() === 'true'));
    });

    function showCallback(geocodeResult, parsedGeocodeResult) {
        $('#callback_result').text(JSON.stringify(parsedGeocodeResult, null, 4));
    }
    // Update zoom field
    var map = $("#addresspicker_map").addresspicker("map");
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
        $('#zoom').val(map.getZoom());
    });

});
```